# hooking into the start of all submit actions

Tags: jquery, submit, hook

I have some code which will show an spinning image whenever ajax is doing something.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.progress').hide();

    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        //alert('starting');
        $('.progress').show();
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('.progress').hide();
    });

});
```

Works fine, but if after ajax is done and a submit occurs, the image will no longer show.  I'd like the image to keep showing up right up until the page get redirected.  Is there a way for me to hook into all submits in the same way I can hook into the start and end of all ajax calls?  Or some other work around, hopefully one that can be solved with one function for all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a non-AJAX submit is called all execution on the current page stops. You may want to submit via AJAX and perform a redirect on a success callback instead.

Comment: So I do a search, see the image pop up and disappear, i'm assuming it's submiting after the image disapears, and in that time, i can click off of the modal the form is in, and click on form elements on the main page, wouldn't this functionality be impossible oif execution on the current page stops.  If I comment out the .hide line on ajax stop, and try it out, the image doesn't stop spinning, but the image would stop spinning if I set async = false.  So when you say execution stop, is it a different execution stop then what happens when async is false?

Comment: async = false means stop until the response is received. In this case it stops during your ajax call, as opposed to waiting for the server response after a normal form POST. The only difference is which line if code it is the queue when the stop occurs.

Comment: But when async = false, I experience a complete freeze, while when I have a submit, a total freeze doesn't occur which makes me think process are still occurring.  Hence perhaps the ability to show an image.

Comment: When you say "submit is called execution on the current page stops." Does execution only stop during the sending of the data. Execution can still occur while the server is processing what was sent right, that's just what it seems like to me based on the behavior of the web page?

Comment: When you submit a non-ajax submit everything stops until the server spits out a new page.

Comment: so in this code snippet
`$('#shapeSearchFormBtn').click(function(){
 $('#shapeSearchForm').submit();
 alert('will i pop up if submit was just called?');
});`
you would expect alert to not occur?  even though it will pop up, sorry for being a bother, it just doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393817/call-a-function-after-a-form-is-submitted-using-javascript-jquery
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171019/how-to-continue-runing-execution-after-form-submit